# Tabela com primeira linha fixa usando Material Design Lite

Tags: html5, table, posicionamento

Olá estou usando o Material Design Lite, preciso deixar fixo a primeira linha da tabela e rolar o resto do conteúdo.

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">USER</th>
              <th>E-MAIL</th>
              <th>ACCESS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td>$2.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>$1.25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, talvez esse código te ajude, adaptei a resposta do seguinte post: [fixed table header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers) para o seu problema.

O código abaixo mostra uma tabela com o cabeçalho fixo utilizando **Material Design Lite**, caso precise alterar a largura da tabela é só mudar a largura da div de fora.

```js
 function scrolify(tblAsJQueryObject, height){
        var oTbl = tblAsJQueryObject;

        // for very large tables you can remove the four lines below
        // and wrap the table with <div> in the mark-up and assign
        // height and overflow property  
        var oTblDiv = $("<div/>");
        oTblDiv.css('height', height);
        oTblDiv.css('overflow','scroll');               
        oTbl.wrap(oTblDiv);

        // save original width
        oTbl.attr("data-item-original-width", oTbl.width());
        oTbl.find('thead tr td').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("data-item-original-width",$(this).width());
        }); 
        oTbl.find('tbody tr:eq(0) td').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("data-item-original-width",$(this).width());
        });                 


        // clone the original table
        var newTbl = oTbl.clone();

        // remove table header from original table
        oTbl.find('thead tr').remove();                 
        // remove table body from new table
        newTbl.find('tbody tr').remove();   

        oTbl.parent().parent().prepend(newTbl);
        newTbl.wrap("<div/>");

        // replace ORIGINAL COLUMN width                
        newTbl.width(newTbl.attr('data-item-original-width'));
        newTbl.find('thead tr td').each(function(){
            $(this).width($(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
        });     
        oTbl.width(oTbl.attr('data-item-original-width'));      
        oTbl.find('tbody tr:eq(0) td').each(function(){
            $(this).width($(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
        });                 
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        scrolify($('#tblNeedsScrolling'), 160); // 160 is height
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:80%;border:1px green black;">
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp" width="100%" id="tblNeedsScrolling">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric" style="width: 55%;">USER</th>
              <th>E-MAIL</th>
              <th>ACCESS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td>$2.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>$1.25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
   
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifiquei na documentação se tinha algo pronto para fixar o `thead`, como não achei, fiz um exemplo em css, e para isso teria que fixar o `tbody` em um tamanho, segue abaixo:

```css
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}

tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
          <thead class="scroll">
            <tr>
              <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">USER</th>
              <th>E-MAIL</th>
              <th>ACCESS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td>$2.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>$1.25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```